# Javascript object key/value is returning undefined

Tags: javascript, json, object

I'm using a `$.each` statement to loop through **JSON** and after creating the object, it's being displayed correctly on the console.log, but says it has no keys. Below are the methods being used and the console.log output.

JS: (This is in a `$.extend(Account.prototype)` to create the methods

```
getDuration: function(type){
    var data = {},
        type = type;

    $.get('/service/account/ajaxdata?method=duration&type='+type, function(response){
        console.log(response);
        $.each(JSON.parse(response), function(k,v){
            data[v.type] = v.duration;
        });
    });
    return data;
},

getUserRates: function(){
    var duration = this.getDuration('user');

    console.log(duration);       
    console.log(duration['ADDUSER']); 
}
```

Below is the output of the console.log function

```
response:
[{"name":"SUBSCRIPTION","duration":"30","id":"2","type":"BASICSUB","lightning_radius":null,"description":"Basic Subscription"},{"name":"ADDUSER","duration":"30","id":"3","type":"ADDUSER","lightning_radius":null,"description":"Additional User(s)"}]

duration:
Object
     ADDUSER : "30"
     BASICSUB : "30"

duration['ADDUSER']:
undefined
```

And just for the sake of it, Object.keys(duration) returns {}, a blank object. Where am I messing up to grab the value of ADDUSER key?

Comment: I'm confused as to how that existing question answers why I'm getting an undefined value from an object key. If you could explain where on that question this get's answered.

Comment: You are accumulating your `data` object inside the callback passed to `$.get()`. That callback will not be invoked until the HTTP request triggered by `$.get()` completes, but the call to `$.get()` itself completes immediately. Therefore, your code reaches the `return` statement long before any actual response data has been received. JavaScript APIs like that are known as **asynchronous** APIs.